# Changing an Image in UIImageView at runtime

Tags: ios, swift3, uiimageview

I've declared a UIImageView property programmatically in a UIScrollView

```
var scrollView: UIScrollView!    
var imageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "OPA_farm.png"))
let drawView = UIView()
```

The reason I initialised it with "OPA_farm.png" is it's the only way I can get an oversized image that scrolls properly

In viewDidLoad they get added as subviews

```
    // other stuff here
    myView.addSubview(scrollView)
    myView.addSubview(drawView)
    scrollView.addSubview(imageView)
```

but changing a UISegmentedControl sender is supposed to change the image ( among other things )

```
@IBAction func chooseFarm(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {
        switch farmSegment.selectedSegmentIndex {
        case 1:
            imageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "OF_farm.png"))
            // other things
            break
        default:
            imageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "OPA_farm.png"))
            // other things
      }
}
```

The other things change but the .png image doesn't. Things I've searched on before ( and during ) posting and tried have been

- imageView.reloadInputViews()
- imageView.setNeedsDisplay()

These things didn't seem to apply

- DispatchQueue.main.async related
- parsing for a tableView related

Following the QuickHelp Inspector to the Apple docs gives sparse info and in Objective C. I know I can use the conversion function to current Swift syntax in XCode 8 and it agrees with other posts along the way in that I seem to be doing everything correctly. I'm Beat. Can someone de-mystify?

Comment: using self.imageView instead of just imageView in the function makes no difference btw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have an image view, you don't need to create new ones (every time you hit your button).

You could declare these at the top of your class (with the imageView)

```
let ofImage = UIImage(named: "OF_farm.png")
let opaImage = UIImage(named: "OPA_farm.png")
```

and in your case statement just reassign either image to your imageView

```
    switch farmSegment.selectedSegmentIndex {
    case 1:
        imageView.image = ofImage
        // other things
        break
    default:
        imageView.image = opaImage
        // other things
  }
```

In viewDidLoad, after adding the imageView to the scrollView you can add auto layout constraints if they are needed. Just be sure to set this first:

```
 imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
```

One last note: Don't forget to view your work in the simulator along the way using the 7+ and the SE settings (and others) to ensure that you have something that will work for everyone.

Comment: actually.., imageView.image = UIImage(named: "XXX_farm.png")  is all I had to change in my switch cases. Yes I was creating new ones unnecessarily. I haven't yet done other stuff you suggest, but I can see what advantage it offers in good technique. I'm side-loading it for a local farming company, its far too specific for their needs to consider publishing to the App Store, but I will be considering them using different size devices.

Comment: Excellent. Glad I could help. Sounds like a fun project to be working on!